# Transforming array into json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this array

```
$params_array['application_id'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$params_array['v'] = 1.20;
$params_array['src'] = 'http://www.google.com/logos/2011/yokoyama11-hp.jpg';
$params_array['functions']['name'] = 'blur';
$params_array['functions']['params']['radius'] = '0.0';
$params_array['functions']['params']['sigma'] = '2.0';
$params_array['functions']['save']['image_identifier'] = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
```

I need to transform it into json.

So I am doing this:

```
$json = json_encode($params_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The result is

```
{"application_id":"xxx","v":1.2,"src":"http://www.google.com/logos/2011/yokoyama11-hp.jpg","functions":{"name":"blur","params":{"radius":"0.0","sigma":"2.0"},"save":{"image_identifier":"MY_CLIENT_ID"}}}
```

but, the receiver API of that json wants it to be formed slightly different, like this:

```
{"application_id":"xxx","v":1.2,"src":"http://www.google.com/logos/2011/yokoyama11-hp.jpg","functions":[{"name":"blur","params":{"radius":"0.0","sigma":"2.0"},"save":{"image_identifier":"MY_CLIENT_ID"}}]}
```

The difference:  after "functions": there is this bracket [, and it's closed at the end.

PHP somehow does not create the json with this bracket.

How can I get PHP to create the json with those brackets?

The receiver API is http://www.blitline.com/docs/quickstart

Comment: What is the receiver API?

Comment: The output from json_encode is correct JSON-syntax. Review your receiver API so that this is correct. Try your different versions here; http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So receiver expects `functions` to be array objects, but you pass single object instead. Change `$params_array['functions']['name']` to `$params_array['functions'][$functionIndex]['name']`

Comment: Will do, but stackoverflow says wait 7 minutes

Comment: wouldn't this create a new array for every property besides `name`? `params` and `save` should be in the same array as `name`

Comment: Yes, so you have to put explicit index

Answer (score 2):

You should prepare your structure this way:

```
$params_array['application_id'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$params_array['v'] = 1.20;
$params_array['src'] = 'http://www.google.com/logos/2011/yokoyama11-hp.jpg';
$params_array['functions'][0]['name'] = 'blur';
$params_array['functions'][0]['params']['radius'] = '0.0';
$params_array['functions'][0]['params']['sigma'] = '2.0';
$params_array['functions'][0]['save']['image_identifier'] = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
```

(Making functions to a number indexed array.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` if you have PHP 5.4.0 or later :

`$json = json_encode($params_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES + JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES'

Comment: ... In PHP <5.4.0 . This constant, which the author included in his question, is available since PHP 5.4.0. http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$params_array['application_id'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$params_array['v'] = 1.20;
$params_array['src'] = 'http://www.google.com/logos/2011/yokoyama11-hp.jpg';
$function_array['name'] = 'blur';
$function_array['params']['radius'] = '0.0';
$function_array['params']['sigma'] = '2.0';
$function_array['save']['image_identifier'] = 'MY_CLIENT_ID'; 
$params_array['functions'] = array($function_array);
```

Reason:
`JSON_ENCODE` will treat an Array as `JSON OBJECT` if it is like `Key=>Value`
and it will treat as `json array` if it is index based like `[0] => value`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, run this example then you'll know how to achieve it.

```
$params_array = array();
$params_array['application_id'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$params_array['another_array'] = array("A","B","C");
echo json_encode($params_array );
```

Result: {"application_id":"xxxxxxxxx","another_array":["A","B","C"]}